# Symmetrize a function

Tags: function-construction

I am working with a function in several variables. I need a function which symmetrizes it. Namely in case of two variables it is f[x, y]+f[y, x]. For three variables it is 
$$f[x , y , z] + f[x, z, y] + f[y, z, x] + f[y, x, z] + 
 f[z, x, y] + f[z, y, x]$$

Generally one has two write $n!$ terms, you know. For n=4 it is 24 (and I found it a bit annoying).

**Question** How to symmetrize a function of several variables in general?

Comment: Try `Total[f @@@ Permutations[{x, y, z}]]`. You could consider using `Mean[]` instead of `Total[]`.

Comment: @J. M. It do work for three variables. What do you do for 4 variables (my first guess did not work).

Comment: What are your four variables? Just replace the list within `Permutations[]` with what you have.

Comment: Ou! It was just my misprint! It do work for any number of variables. Total[f @@@ Permutations[{x, y, z, t}]] Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you understand how `Permutations[]` and `@@@` works, consider answering your own question.

Comment: @J.M.`Tr@Permutations[f[x, y, z]]`...

Comment: @ciao, yes, that works nicely for a symbolic function and symbolic arguments.

Comment: See page 169 in Introduction to Stochastic Integration by Hui-Hsiung Kuo, for example.

Comment: Closely related: [What is the command to find function invariant?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7795/245)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an implementation of the hints provided in the comments (predominantly by [**J. M. is computer-less**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-is-computer-less) but also [**ciao**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao), too).

Initially, store the function arguments needed in a variable eg `args = {x, y, z}`.

Note that the list of arguments stored in `args` holds three distinct arguments namely `x`, `y` and `z`. This fact is due to the example provided in the *Question*.

There's nothing stopping one to use more (eg four) or less (eg two) arguments.

Next, using [*`Permutations`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) one can obtain "...*a list of all possible permutations of the elements*" as in:

```
perms = Permutations[args]
```

> ```
> {{x, y, z}, {x, z, y}, {y, x, z}, {y, z, x}, {z, x, y}, {z, y, x}}
> ```

Now, `perms` holds a list of *permutations* of the arguments in `args` (see above).

The next step should transform the list of permutations into a *sum* of functions applied to those arguments. This end can be achieved with several ways; one way (suggested by *J. M. is computer-less*) is to use [*`Apply`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply) at the first level of the expression in `perms` or `f @@@ perms` which is shorthand for `Apply[f, perms, {1}]` and *both* evaluate to

> ```
> {f[x, y, z], f[x, z, y], f[y, x, z], f[y, z, x], f[z, x, y], f[z, y, x]}
> ```

Finally, in order to obtain the *sum* of the function `f` applied to all the permutations of the supplied arguments there are a number of suggestions:

1. One suggestion is to use [*`Total`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) which produces the sum of the elements of the list it is provided with as an argument: `Total[f @@@ perms]`
2. Another suggestion (by *ciao*) is to use [*`Tr`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html) which produces the trace of a matrix -*1*-: `Tr[f @@@ perms]`.

Both suggestions produce the desired result, namely

```
f[x, y, z] + f[x, z, y] + f[y, x, z] + f[y, z, x] + f[z, x, y] +  f[z, y, x]
```

Note how using `args = {x, y}` instead of the three-element list that was used so far, and reproducing all the intermediate steps shown above would produce `f[x, y] + f[y, x]` as expected.

**Endnotes**

*1*- A list is treated both as... well, a *list*... as in '*a collection of elements*' but it is also treated as a *vector*, too; compare and contrast `{x, y, z}` with `{{x}, {y}, {z}}`; the former is a *list* while the later is a *vector* as in its [*`Dimensions`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html?q=Dimensions) are `{3,1}` or $3\times1$ as opposed to the dimensions of the former one which are `{3}`. So `Tr[{x, y, z}]` is equivalent to `Tr[{{x}, {y}, {z}}]`.

---

The following code block summarizes the steps taken in this *Answer* into a function called `makeSymmetric`:

```
makeSymmetric::usage = "makeSymmetric[f, args] returns the sum of the permutations of the list 'args', after symbol 'f' has been applied to them.";
makeSymmetric[f_, args_] := Total[f @@@ Permutations[args]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Permute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) with [`SymmetricGroup[3]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricGroup.html) as the second argument:

```
Total @ Permute[f[x, y, z], SymmetricGroup @ 3]
```

> f[x, y, z] + f[x, z, y] + f[y, x, z] + f[y, z, x] + f[z, x, y] + f[z, y, x]