# How to make an expression manifestly invariant under a symmetry?

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

**Context**

> I would like to have a function which  symmetrizes and simplifies  a symbolic expression to highlight its internal symmetries.

I believe such a function would be *extremely useful* for post processing symbolic expressions to be published in scientific papers because the expectation is that formulas should be presented in ways which highlight such symmetries when possible.

Let us consider a specific example based on a Kullback distance :

```
tt = ResourceFunction["KullbackLeiblerDivergence"][
    NormalDistribution[m1, s1], NormalDistribution[m2, s2]] +
   ResourceFunction["KullbackLeiblerDivergence"][
    NormalDistribution[m2, s2], NormalDistribution[m1, s1]] // 
  FullSimplify
```

[image]

This expression should by construction be symmetric with respect to switching s1 and s2 or m1 and m2 . Indeed I can compute by hand a more symmetric version

```
tt2 = (tt /. m2 -> m1 // 
    FullSimplify) + (tt /. s2 -> s1 // FullSimplify)/
   2 + (tt /. s1 -> s2 // FullSimplify)/2
```

[image]

and one can check it is equal to the previous expression:

```
tt2 - tt // FullSimplify
```

(* 0 *)

---

**Question**

> How to automate this process for arbitrary expressions (whose symmetry may be given as an argument)?

Can one write a function which Simplifies while preserving symmetries?

For instance in the above example, I would like `Symmetrize[tt,{{s1,s2},{m1,m2}}]` to return `tt2`.

In fact, ideally one could aim for an extension of
`FullSimplify` which would be called something like `HighlightSymmetries->True` so that

```
  FullSimplify[tt,HighlightSymmetries->True]
```

would return `tt2`.

---

**Attempt**

This [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190297/1089) suggests using

```
Permute[tt, GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[3], {2}]] // 
  Tr[#]/Length[#] & // Expand
```

[image]

which is a first step but is unfortunately not as simple as it should be.

---

**Update**

It would be great if the solution could also simplify symmetrically expressions such as

```
  ((m1 - m2)^2*s1^2 + s1^4 + 
 ((m1 - m2)^2 - 2*s1^2)*s2^2 + s2^4)/
  (2*s1^2*s2^2) + 
 ((m3 - m4)^2*s3^2 + s3^4 + 
  ((m3 - m4)^2 - 2*s3^2)*s4^2 + s4^4)/
   (2*s3^2*s4^2)
```

Into

[image]

i.e. highlighting higher order symmetries

[image]

I do realise this is not an easy question!
But I feel it would be very useful in general.

Comment: How automated do you want this to be? For example, you can achieve your desired form by using manually constructed `ComplexityFunction` inside `FullSimplify`: `FullSimplify[tt2, ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] - 1000 Count[#, m1 - m2 | s1^2 - s2^2, All] &)]`. I guess this could be somehow generalized to automatically look for variables, then construct a few simple symmetric terms, like $(a+b), (a-b)^2, (a^2 - b^2)^2 \dots$, to be used inside `ComplexityFunction`.

Comment: @Domen thank you. Yes it would be great if the algorithm could find the complexity function itself.

Comment: I think the question is not clear enough but can relate to the [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial). The MMA functions are e.g. `SymmetricPolynomial`, `PolynomialReduce`, `SymmetricReduction`.

Comment: I think you are a bit contradicting yourself. Writing `(m1-m2)^2` is not a symmetric way to write it although the polynomial itself is symmetric in `m1` and `m2`. Symmetric way to write it would be: `(m1+m2)^2 - 4 m1 m2` but this is not simpler than the previous writing. So you can not have both simplicity and symmetric writing at the same time in general. So what you prefer - the real symmetric writing of it or simplicity of it?

Comment: @azerbajdzan I would like the simplest which also displays symmetries or antisymmetries when possible. In an ideal world it would be great to add an option to `FullSimplify` which would be called `HighlightSymmetries->True` to automate the process.

Comment: @Lacia Thank you for the link: is there also such a thing as anti-symmetric polynomials? They also display a certain amount of 'symmetry'?

Answer (score 4):

If you want manifest $m_1\leftrightarrow m_2$ and $s_1\leftrightarrow s_2$ symmetry you can introduce the variables $M=m_1-m_2$, $S=s_1+s_2$ and $T=s_1s_2$ such that

```
tt /. m1 -> M + m2 /. Solve[{s1 + s2 == S, s1 s2 == T}, {s1, s2}][[1]] // FullSimplify // Expand
```

with result
$$
\frac{M^2 S^2}{2 T^2}-\frac{M^2}{T}+\frac{S^4}{2 T^2}-\frac{2 S^2}{T}
$$
which is indeed manifestly symmetric. You can of course undo the change of variables if you wish,
$$
\frac{(\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2 (\text{s1}+\text{s2})^2}{2 \text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2}-\frac{(\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2}{\text{s1} \text{s2}}+\frac{(\text{s1}+\text{s2})^4}{2 \text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2}-\frac{2 (\text{s1}+\text{s2})^2}{\text{s1} \text{s2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could this kind of transformation be automated?
BTW your final expression does not explicitly show the  odd parity  in s1<->s2.

Comment: The expression is not odd under $s_1\leftrightarrow s_2$, it is *even*. I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Also, your new expression can be simplified using the same trick, `exp /. Solve[{s1 + s2 == S1, s1 s2 == T1}, {s1, s2}][[1]] /. Solve[{s3 + s4 == S2, s3 s4 == T2}, {s3, s4}][[1]] // FullSimplify` which yields $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{-2 \text{T1} \left((\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2+2 \text{S1}^2\right)+\text{S1}^2 (\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2+\text{S1}^4}{\text{T1}^2}+\frac{-2 \text{T2} \left((\text{m3}-\text{m4})^2+2 \text{S2}^2\right)+\text{S2}^2 (\text{m3}-\text{m4})^2+\text{S2}^4}{\text{T2}^2}\right)$$ where the symmetry is again manifest.

Answer (score 3):

## New Version

This version finds the simplest form for the original case of 4 variables but fails to find the simplest form for the added case of 8 variables. The failure seems to be linked to Mathematica not deciding to simplify a quantity of the form -8ab+(a+b)^2 to (a-b)^2-4ab at an intermediate step presumably because the leaf count is similar. One could maybe try  to make a complexity function or provide transformation rules for simplify but I am not sure what is the most general choice.

**Outline**

- Code
- Explanation
- Example

### Code (an explanation can be found in the next section)

```
symSimpPoly[expression_,symVars_]:=
Module[{symmetricParts,newExpression,symmetricPartsDef,toOriginal},
    (*Name the symmetric polynomials*)
    symmetricParts=Table[Unique[t],Length[First@symVars]];    (*Define the symmetric polynomials whose name were given in symmetricParts*)
    symmetricPartsDef=Table[
    SymmetricPolynomial[j,First@symVars]
    ,{j,Length[First@symVars]}];
    (*Rule that expresses the symmetric polynomials in symmetricParts in terms of their definitions in symmetricPartsDef*)
    toOriginal=Thread[symmetricParts->symmetricPartsDef];
    newExpression=SymmetricReduction[expression,First@symVars,symmetricParts][[1]];
    newExpression=Collect[newExpression,symmetricParts,If[NumericQ[#]==True,#,Hold[#]]&]/.toOriginal//Simplify;
    newExpression=newExpression/. Hold[s_]:>Hold[symSimpPoly[s,Rest[symVars]]];
    newExpression//ReleaseHold
]
```

### Explanation

#### code usage

```
symSimpPoly[polynomial expression, variables grouped by symmetry:{{x11,x12,...},{x21,x22,...}}]
```

#### code explanation

{{ The section between double curly brackets is copy pasted from the previous version with correction "code below->code above".

The code above works for polynomials that are symmetric over permutations of subsets of their variables. For example, the numerator of

```
tt=(s2^2*((m1 - m2)^2 - 2*s1^2) + s1^2*(m1 - m2)^2 + s1^4 + s2^4)/(2*s1^2*s2^2)
```

is symmetric with respect to the subset `{s1,s2}` and with respect to the subset `{m1,m2}`.

If one wishes to use the code above, it is then necessary to be able to identify subexpressions of an expression that are polynomial and symmetric. In the case of the question by OP this is given by the numerator and denominator. I leave a general purpose symmetric polynomial finder as a separate question that I will not try to answer at this present time.

The code above uses `SymmetricReduction` as suggested by @Lacia in the comments below the original post. As such it only works for polynomial expressions and so polynomial sub expressions should be identified beforehand.

}}

The code works recursively. At each step:

Reduction of the expression into named symmetric polynomials, that is, a symmetric polynomial is replaced by a variable. By setting the symmetric polynomials to be variables we can then collect the coefficients that depend on other variables and apply recursively the same function on those coefficients. Before moving on to the coefficients the expression is simplified.

### Example

The polynomial in the numerator is invariant with respect to the symmetry `si->-si` as the polyonomial can be written as a polynomial in `si^2`. We therefore use the variable `ssi=si^2` to make the even symmetry explicit. This allows us to avoid writing the expression awkwardy in terms of symmetric polyonmials such as s1+s2 which are not invariant with respect the even symmetry.

```
newt=symSimpPoly[Numerator[tt]/.{s1^m_->ss1^(m/2),s2^m_->ss2^(m/2)},{{ss1,ss2},{m1,m2}}]/Denominator[tt]/.ss1->s1^2/.ss2->s2^2
```

$$\frac{(\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2 \left(\text{s1}^2+\text{s2}^2\right)+\left(\text{s1}^2-\text{s2}^2\right)^2}{2 \text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2}$$

```
newtt==tt//FullSimplify
```

In the case of the new expression with 8 variables the code finds a non optimal simplification

```
tt2=((m1 - m2)^2*s1^2 + s1^4 + 
 ((m1 - m2)^2 - 2*s1^2)*s2^2 + s2^4)/
  (2*s1^2*s2^2) + 
 ((m3 - m4)^2*s3^2 + s3^4 + 
  ((m3 - m4)^2 - 2*s3^2)*s4^2 + s4^4)/
   (2*s3^2*s4^2)
auxtt2=tt2 /.{s1^m_->ss1^(m/2),s2^m_->ss2^(m/2),s3^m_->ss3^(m/2),s4^m_->ss4^(m/2)}//Together;
newt=symSimpPoly[Numerator[auxtt2],{{ss1,ss2},{ss3,ss4},{m1,m2},{m3,m4}}]/Denominator[auxtt2]/.{ss1->s1^2,ss2->s2^2,ss3->s3^2,ss4->s4^2}//TeXForm//ToString
```

### $$
\frac{\text{s3}^2 \text{s4}^2 (\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2 \left(\text{s1}^2+\text{s2}^2\right)+\text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2 \left((\text{m3}-\text{m4})^2 \left(\text{s3}^2+\text{s4}^2\right)-8 \text{s3}^2 \text{s4}^2+\left(\text{s3}^2+\text{s4}^2\right)^2\right)+\text{s3}^2 \text{s4}^2 \left(\text{s1}^2+\text{s2}^2\right)^2}{2 \text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2 \text{s3}^2 \text{s4}^2}$$

## Previous version

**Outline**

- Code
- Explanation
- Example

### Code (an explanation can be found in the next section)

```
symSimpPoly[exp_,symVars_]:=
Module[{iterations,symmetricParts,newExp,degree,symmetricPartsDef,toOriginal,newExpSimp,originalSimp,subExpressions},


iterations=Length[symVars];
symmetricParts=ConstantArray[{},iterations];(*Store symmetric polynomials*)
newExp=exp; (*Initialization of the rewriting of exp*)


Do[
    symmetricParts[[i]]=Table[Unique[t],Length[symVars[[i]]]];(*Name the symmetric polynomials*)
    newExp=SymmetricReduction[newExp,symVars[[i]],symmetricParts[[i]]][[1]];
,{i,iterations}];

(*Define the symmetric polynomials whose name were given in symmetricParts*)
symmetricPartsDef=Table[
    Table[
        SymmetricPolynomial[j,symVars[[i]]]
        ,{j,Length[symVars[[i]]]}]
,{i,iterations}];

    (*Rule that expresses the symmetric polynomials in symmetricParts in terms of their definitions in symmetricPartsDef*)
toOriginal=Thread[Flatten[symmetricParts]->Flatten[symmetricPartsDef]];

(*---Start:Optional Simplifying stage. Can be changed or deleted----*)

newExpSimp=newExp//Simplify;
subExpressions=Cases[Level[newExpSimp,-1],_Plus];
originalSimp=subExpressions/.toOriginal//FullSimplify;
newExp=newExpSimp/.Thread[subExpressions->originalSimp];(*Partially revert to the original variables in symdvars*)

(*---Finish:Optional Simplifying stage. Can be changed or deleted---*)

newExp/.toOriginal
]
```

### Explanation

#### code usage

```
symSimpPoly[expression, variables grouped by symmetry:{{x11,x12,...},{x21,x22,...}}]
```

#### code explanation

The code below works for polynomials that are symmetric over permutations of subsets of their variables. For example, the numerator of

```
tt=(s2^2*((m1 - m2)^2 - 2*s1^2) + s1^2*(m1 - m2)^2 + s1^4 + s2^4)/(2*s1^2*s2^2)
```

is symmetric with respect to the subset `{s1,s2}` and with respect to the subset `{m1,m2}`.

If one wishes to use the code above, it is then necessary to be able to identify subexpressions of an expression that are polynomial and symmetric. In the case of the question by OP this is given by the numerator and denominator. I leave a general purpose symmetric polynomial finder as a separate question that I will not try to answer at this present time.

The code above uses `SymmetricReduction` as suggested by @Lacia in the comments below the original post. As such it only works for polynomial expressions and so polynomial sub expressions should be identified beforehand. The code works in 2 stages:

1. Stage 1: Reduce the expression into named symmetric polynomials, that is, a symmetric polynomial is replaced by a variable. The auxiliary variables are used to : 1: prevent the reduction in terms of symmetric polynomials from 1 symmetry from deconstructing the symmetric polynomials from another symmetry; 2: facilitate the identification of combinations of symmetric polynomials that can be combined to find a simpler expression.
2. Stage 2 : Gather symmetric polynomials and simplify them in the hope they lead to a simpler expression. An example is given by @azerbajdzan in the comments below the original post
   : `(m1+m2)^2 - 4 m1 m2` is more complex than `(m1-m2)^2`. I would imagine that trying all possible combinations of symmetric polynomials would lead to a fairly slow program. Instead, I rely on the hope that `Simplify` will identify combinations of symmetric polynomials that can be factored in subexpressions and I let `FullSimplify` try to simplify those subexpression once they are written in terms of the original variables (for example `s1,s2,m1,m2` in the example expression by OP) instead of in terms of the named symmetric polynomials (which is the way that the expression is written at stage 1).

### Example

The polynomial in the numerator is invariant with respect to the symmetry `si->-si` as the polyonomial can be written as a polynomial in `si^2`. We therefore use the variable `ssi=si^2` to make the even symmetry explicit. This allows us to avoid writing the expression awkwardy in terms of symmetric polyonmials such as s1+s2 which are not invariant with respect the even symmetry.

```
newt=symSimpPoly[Numerator[tt]/.{s1^m_->ss1^(m/2),s2^m_->ss2^(m/2)},{{ss1,ss2},{m1,m2}}]/Denominator[tt]/.ss1->s1^2/.ss2->s2^2
```

$$\frac{(\text{m1}-\text{m2})^2 \left(\text{s1}^2+\text{s2}^2\right)-4 \text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2+\left(\text{s1}^2+\text{s2}^2\right)^2}{2 \text{s1}^2 \text{s2}^2}$$

```
newtt==tt//FullSimplify
```

**Note**

The simplification to (s1^2-s2^2)^2 did not occur because there was no factorization in the intermediate expression written in terms of the auxiliary symmetric polynomials (the auxiliary variables were renamed below):

```
t1^2  - 4 t2 + t1 (t3^2  - 4 t4)
```

In general, with many more terms in the sum,  I think there would be too many subexpressions to consider with a brute force approach. Hence, I rather not try to modify the code such that it works for the particular case of the example by OP while slowing down the code in maybe most cases.

Comment: Notice that for m1=m2 the numerator also has translation symmetry s1^2->s1^2+a,s2^2->s2^2+a. I would expect that one could simply expand over polynomials that respect the symmetries and properties of the original expression and then find the coefficients of the expansion using something like `PolynomialReduce` or `SolveAlways`. This however requires the effort of noticing more than permutation symmetry. Different types of common symmetries could maybe be checked in a more advance code.

Comment: Thank you for this more exhaustive answer. Why does your code fail to see that part of the final expression can be written more symmetrically as (s1^2-s2^2)^2?

Comment: @chris I tried to explain it in the note. The code uses a guess/heuristic to group terms together in the hope that simplifying them first will lead to a simpler expression. In an arbitrary expression there are many possible ways to group the symmetric polynomials together. I simply tried to use Simplify to factor terms and to try to simplify the inner most factors. The s1^2 and s1^2 terms were not grouped as a factor because there is nothing that multiplies them in the numerator of the expression provided unlike (m1-m2)^2

Comment: For polynomial expressions, the cleanest way might be to find all symmetries and properties of the expression and expand in those terms as in the first comment.

Comment: Thank you again for your extensive answer: pity I could not award two bounties.

Comment: @chris No problem whatever works best but maybe consider accepting the answer that got the bounty so that other users can see it first as I had to scroll down a bit to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of collecting variables and simplifying, that can help. At least in this expression, it's possible to do it in the following way:

```
f[expr_, vars_List] := Total[
    Map[Function[
     If[FreeQ[#, Apply[Alternatives, vars]], #, Apart @ #]],
            Divide[
                Map[Simplify,
                    Map[Total,
                        Values[
                                GroupBy[
                                    
         MonomialList[Collect[Numerator @ expr, vars, Simplify], vars],
                                    FreeQ[#, Apply[Alternatives, vars]] &,
                                    Simplify
                                ]
                            ]
                    ]
                ],
                Denominator @ expr
            ]
        ]
   ];
```

In your example, we collect in the variables $m_1$ and $m_2$:

```
f[tt, {m1, m2}]
```

[image]

**Note**: I would like to see more examples to seek generalization of this path.

**Update 1**: The version for two or more polynomials, assuming you first group the polynomials using GroupBy with their respective variables and add the resulting expressions, as you provide in your new example.

```
SymPolySimplify[expr_, vars_?VectorQ] /; SameQ[Head @ expr, Times] := 
  Total[
    Map[Function[
     If[FreeQ[#, Apply[Alternatives, vars]], #, Apart @ #]],
            Divide[
                Map[Simplify,
                    Map[Total,
                        Values[
                                GroupBy[
                                    
         MonomialList[Collect[Numerator @ expr, vars, Simplify], vars],
                                    FreeQ[#, Apply[Alternatives, vars]] &,
                                    Simplify
                                ]
                            ]
                    ]
                ],
                Denominator @ expr
            ]
        ]
   ];

SymPolySimplify[expr_, vars_?MatrixQ] /; SameQ[Head @ expr, Plus] := 
  Total[
    Table[SymPolySimplify[Part[Level[expr, {1}], i], vars[[i]]],
            {i, Length @ vars}
        ]
   ];
```

Using the function `SymPolySimplify` with the two examples provided:

```
SymPolySimplify[tt, {m1, m2}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
SymPolySimplify[tt2, {{m1, m2}, {m3, m4}}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

**Update 2**: Below I show you a version of function `SymPolySimplify` using `SymmetricReduction`.

```
SymPolySimplify[expr_, vars_?VectorQ] /; SameQ[Head @ expr, Times] := 
  Total[
    Map[
            Function[
     If[FreeQ[#, Apply[Alternatives, vars]], Simplify @ #, #]],
            Values[
                GroupBy[
                    Simplify[
                      First[Map[Level[#, {1}] &, SymmetricReduction[expr, vars]]]
                    ],
                    FreeQ[#, Apply[Alternatives, vars]] &,
                    Function @ Apart @ Simplify @ Total @ #
                ]
            ]
        ]
   ];

 SymPolySimplify[expr_, vars_?MatrixQ] /; SameQ[Head @ expr, Plus] := 
  Total[
    Table[SymPolySimplify[Part[Level[expr, {1}], i], vars[[i]]],
            {i, Length @ vars}
        ]
   ];
```

Using the new version of the `SymPolySimplify` function with the two examples provided:

```
SymPolySimplify[tt, {m1, m2}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
SymPolySimplify[tt2, {{m1, m2}, {m3, m4}}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Probably, this needs a more elegant way to optimize the process, by considering symmetries. However, dealing with more complex expressions than those you provided as examples requires a different approach. It might be beneficial to manipulate matrices associated with polynomials in multiple variables, and then propose a solution based on that perspective that aligns with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, I just want to point out that OP's simplified form of the expression is in fact not the simplest one.

OP's form:

```
(m1 - m2)^2/(2 s1^2) + (m1 - m2)^2/(2 s2^2) + (s1^2 - s2^2)^2/(2 s1^2 s2^2)
% // LeafCount
```

> $$\frac{(m1-m2)^2}{2 s1^2}+\frac{(m1-m2)^2}{2 s2^2}+\frac{\left(s1^2-s2^2\right)^2}{2 s1^2 s2^2}$$
>
> $50$

But there is a simpler form:

```
PolynomialReduce[tt, {m1 - m2, s1 - s2}, {m1, m2, s1, s2}] // 
  FullSimplify;
First[%] . {m1 - m2, s1 - s2} + Last[%] // FullSimplify
LeafCount[%]
```

> $$\frac{(m1-m2)^2 \left(s1^2+s2^2\right)+\left(s1^2-s2^2\right)^2}{2 s1^2 s2^2}$$
>
> $37$

Comment: good point! So the answer should produce this automatically :0)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, its not possible to find the symmetry group of an expression without prior knowlegde.  If a symmetry is clear from construction or suspected, just use the representation of primitive generators of the group:

```
    tt/.{s1->\[Sigma]1+\[Sigma]2,s2->\[Sigma]1-\[Sigma]2,
         m1->\[Mu]1+\[Mu]2,m2:> \[Mu]1-\[Mu]2}//
    FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{4 \text{$\mu $2}^2 \left(\text{$\sigma $1}^2+\text{$\sigma $2}^2\right)+8 \text{$\sigma $1}^2 \text{$\sigma $2}^2}{\left(\text{$\sigma $1}^2-\text{$\sigma $2}^2\right)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your post. If needed one could assume that the expected symmetries are given. Incidently your solution seems to have lost mu1

Comment: By a glance.  you may observe that your expression depends on m1-m2 only. Generally, most compact expressions of ratonals arise, if expressed by the linear factors in the characteristical polynomials; but at hand and simple,  unfortunately,  for squraes only.