# Getting error message from repeated function application

Tags: functions

I have a formal group law $f(x, y)$ and I want to compute the repeated application, $f(x,f(x,f(x,f(x,x))))$. When I tell Mathematica to evaluate that my code for repeated application, it says that $f(x,x)$ is not a valid variable.  How do I do  repeated application?

Comment: Related: [What is the command to find function invariant?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7822/245). You'll have to post *Mathematica* code to get a useful answer.

Comment: You need to edit your question, adding the definition you made for `f`, the expression you evaluated to do repeated application, and showing us the actual result Mathematica produced. Without this additional information, there is not much we can say,

Comment: If you are actually asking Mathematica to evaluate forms like `f(x, x)`, that could be part of your problem. `f(x, x)` is not a function call in Mathematica. Use `f[x, x]`.